# Condición dentro de una clausura de array_map devuelve valores de más

Tags: php, clausuras

Tengo este array:

```
<?php 
$array = [
    '0' => ['asset' => 'wadus'],
    '1' => ['asset' => 'wadus2'],
    '2' => ['asset' => ''],
];
?>
```

El `var_dump` del array me devuelve:

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(5) "wadus"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(6) "wadus2"
    }
    [2] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(0) ""
    }
}
```

Si itero con `foreach` puedo discriminar los elementos vacíos.

```
$clean_assets = [];

foreach ($array as $asset) {
    if(!empty($asset['asset'])) {
        $clean_assets[] = $asset['asset'];
    } 
}
```

El `var_dump` de `$clean_assets` me devuelve:

```
array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "wadus"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "wadus2"
}
```

Si uso una clausura:

```
$clean_assets = array_map(function($asset) {
    if(!empty($asset['asset'])){
        return $asset['asset'];
    }    
}, $array);
```

Me devuelve esto:

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(5) "wadus"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(6) "wadus2"
    }
    [2] =>
    array(1) {
        'asset' =>
        string(0) ""
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué la función anónima tiene este comportamiento?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a tu primer `foreach`? Simple, ahí sólo lo estás guardando en un arreglo sin relaciones `['wadus','wadus2']`, en el segundo estás creando un arreglo asociativo que contiene llaves `key=>value` `['asset'=>'wadus', 'asset'=>'wadus2']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no sé como te puede salir así la segunda respuesta (aplicando la closure) ya que aplicando tus métodos a mí me aparece de la siguiente forma:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "wadus"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "wadus2"
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
```

Buscando un poco en la **[documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)** de la función `array_map` he encontrado lo siguiente:

> El array devuelto **conservará las claves del argumento array si y solo si se pasa exactamente un array**. Si se pasa más de un array, el array devuelto tendrá claves secuenciales de tipo integer.

Por lo tanto, del párrafo anterior se puede deducir que si le pasas como argumento un sólo array, este conservará su estructura.

He hecho una segunda prueba para comprobar que esto era cierto con otra condición diferente:

```
$clean_assets = array_map(function($asset) {
    if($asset['asset'] == "wadus2"){
       return $asset['asset'];
    }    
}, $array);
```

Con la correspondiente respuesta:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  string(6) "wadus2"
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
```

**Conclusión**: Al pasarle un solo `array` al closure y utilizando la función `array_map`, esta mantendrá la estructura del array original rellenando solamente los valores que coincidan con la condición y dejando a NULL el resto de valores.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un error en el planteamiento, la función `array_filter`, si no se le pasa el *callback* devuelve un array en el que los elementos vacíos quedan eliminados.

*Ejemplo #2*: `array_filter()` sin *callback*:

```
<?php
$entrada = array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => false,
    2 => -1,
    3 => null,
    4 => ''
);
print_r(array_filter($entrada));
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

Fuente del ejemplo: [PHP: `array_filter`](https://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)